# Derive exact types from a typed object

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I want to derive types from constants like this

```
const iso3ToCountry = {
  DEU: {
    name: "Germany",
    continent: "Europe",
    language: "de",
  },
  GBR: {
    name: "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
    continent: "Europe",
    language: "en",
  },
} as const;

type ISOCode = keyof typeof iso3ToCountry // same as "DEU" | "GBR";
```

But, I also want to ensure that the values of the object implement the following interface:

```
interface CountryDetails {
  name: string;
  continent: string;
  language: string;
}
```

The only way, that I have found to achieve both, is to use a helper function

```
function ensureType<T extends Record<string, CountryDetails>>(obj: T): T {
  return obj;
}

const iso3ToCountry = ensureType({
  DEU: {
    name: "Germany",
    continent: "Europe",
    language: "de",
  },
  GBR: {
    name: "United Kingdom",
    continent: "Europe",
    language: "en",
  },
} as const);

type ISOCode = keyof typeof iso3ToCountry;
```

Now `ISOCode` is equivalent to `"DEU" | "GBR"` and every value in the iso3ToCountry
must have a `name`, `continent` and a `language`.

The downside is that the `ensureType` function will be in the compiled JavaScript. We add code to our app, just to solve some compile-time problems.

### Question:

Can I achieve type-checks in the "iso3ToCountry"-object *and* the ability to derive the key-type without having to add code that will remain in the compiled JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really want the so-called `satisfies` operator, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481), but this does not currently exist in TypeScript (as of 4.5).  The generic helper function method you are using is a very common workaround for this, especially because it works for just about any expression.  The extra function call in the emitted JavaScript is usually not a big deal, but you're looking for something with zero runtime impact.

---

A different workaround is to define a type using the [`typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) on a variable of the same type as the expression you want to check,
which will succeed or fail to compiler depending on your desired constraint.

You can't use the `typeof` operator on arbitrary expressions; it has to be a variable or a property of a variable.  So this workaround could have some runtime impact if you need to declare a new variable.

Since you already have a variable named `iso3ToCountry` of the right type, you don't have to define a new variable, so there's no runtime impact.

Here's one way to do it:

```
type CheckIso3ToCountry<T extends Record<keyof T, CountryDetails> =
  typeof iso3ToCountry> = void; 
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <-- you've got a problem with 
// iso3ToCountry if and only if there's an error here
```

Here the `CheckIso3ToCountry<T>` type is a dummy type that evaluates to `void` no matter what.  The important parts are the [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the `T` type parameter forcing it to extend `Record<keyof T, CountryDetails>`, and the [generic parameter default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) of `typeof iso3ToCountry`.  As long as the latter type is assignable to the former, everything's fine.

But if you make a mistake with `iso3ToCountry`:

```
const iso3ToCountry = {
  DEU: {
    name: "Germany",
    continent: "Europe",
    language: "de",
  },
  GBR: {
    name: "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",
    continant: "Europe",
    language: "en",
  },
} as const;
```

Then you'll get an error:

```
type CheckIso3ToCountry<T extends Record<keyof T, CountryDetails> =
  typeof iso3ToCountry> = void; // error!
//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
// Property 'continent' is missing in type 
// '{ readonly name: "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland";
//  readonly continant: "Europe"; readonly language: "en"; }' 
// but required in type 'CountryDetails'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8&jsx=0#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-AAjDAQeoAd1KYyQ1rNqqpGp+vGaAwawAwCh4zXGlgg3puNiZMj8MiQEzaeJIyVrpHA0DgiCQGRAjBBLDu3GT6vF8iUBkMWj0w9BTbMFisNjsaWccLWHkRph8fgCZwXBwxx3im5S87UmRy44Kk9ixVK5SQVShtXqQta7U63SlU0zw1G1amswg80Wh6GKsbigCua47Pu+zokcZinIBdaAVcIA3D2MLPNIljvK2qbyJKgLAgqjaQFiyJQqiQHwsumxIpC0KEduME0Ti+T1oQexKsgogkuSlL9t89KMiybL0ByXIjLy-KCs0Ipivxvz-Ph2qERxKq8dScnakgeoGkapplhWACEiZOiZJkuu6nqSL6-qBv0IbhpGMZxgm+R6X26maum-QLFmOZeQWbTFt5+kjFWhYNiQekAArrpYBJIN6wEIpw3q8DcYB8FA1S8FMHEuWoenergSBtB27B+WCpiXmUlTVPeDTNE+HRtq+vTvj5n4BT+cwDKY5GRWaJXtLU2YKEloHUau2wbkapUjX5DGYrEpxGskqWJkgYYSNwbQAI4SDwbSMH0eXejh8lSkC3oAHQNqxRDJEAA)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer I still have to understand it, but it works. I think I'll stay with the extra function call because it has the advantage of code-completion in the IDE (which wasn't part of the question, but is important to me as well). The "satisfies"-operator seems to be what I really want.

Comment: Updated issue link to follow on this: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920